# Using Paypal PDT with Django

Tags: django

I have integrated paypal with Django successfully.It works well when I make payments through paypal credentials but when I make payment through credit card I get this Djano messsage 
CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.Its the same redirection url /same code for both but somehow for credit payments I get CSRF verification failed message.

Any ideas??

What is different from paypal payment to credit card is when you click on return to site after successful credit card  payment you get this message

"Although this page is encrypted the information you have sent over an unencrypted connection and could be easily read by a third party?Are you sure you want to continue?"

Answer (score 1):

The issue is solved ..Used the following as described in the django docs.

Certain views can have unusual requirements that mean they don't fit the normal pattern envisaged here. A number of utilities can be useful in these situations. The scenarios they might be needed in are described in the following section.
Utilities

csrf_exempt(view)

```
This decorator marks a view as being exempt from the protection ensured by the middleware. Example:

from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

@csrf_exempt
def my_view(request):
    return HttpResponse('Hello world')
```